# Django 1.10: The current URL didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
   url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
   url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout,
          name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
]
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import  include, url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
  url(r'^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
  url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view()
  ,name='post_detail'),
  url(r'^post/new/$', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
  url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.PostUpdateView.as_view()
    , name='post_edit'),
  url(r'^drafts/$', views.DraftListView.as_view()
    , name='post_draft_list'),
  url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.PostDeleteView.as_view()
    ,name='post_remove'),
  url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish
   , name='post_publish'),
  url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post
    , name='add_comment_to_post'),
  url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve
    , name='comment_approve'),
  url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove
    , name='comment_remove'), 
 ]
```

The error occurs when I try to edit, remove the post, add a comment or remove comment from the post

I can't access any url from `blog/urls.py` 
and I don't know where the error is coming from.

**Error**
[image]

Comment: Check the url you are trying to access,  its invalid. It should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/drafts//  (this is what server expecting)  Check the syntax.

Comment: You have an invalid `{% url %}` tag. The problem is on the page where you clicked that link. Please show that template. From the screenshot, it looks as if you have `{ url ... }` instead of `{% url ... %}`.

Comment: `^drafts/$` is making your URL strict match to `drafts/` only, not even `drafts` or `drafts/*`

Comment: @Shubhamoli True, but probably irrelevant. it is highly unlikely Ahmed wants to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/drafts{url+post_detail+pk=post.pk}`. A more likely location would be `127.0.0.1:8000/post_detail/12`

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks, i forgot to add % to the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, you have a link where you have missed out the `%` in the URL tag. You have something like,

```
{ url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk }
```

but it should be:

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}
```

When you click on the invalid link, it takes you to `drafts/{url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk}`, so you get the 404 error.